# how to organize EC2 instances - Do I have to open new account?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have two instances running for one client and wish to launch another instance for a different client.  These clients need access the instances but I wish to secure them so one client is unable to access another's instance.  Is there a way to do this through one customer portal?

Answer (score 2):

`AWS Identity and Access Management` should be able to provide what you need.

From the [AWS IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) page:

**Manage IAM users and their access** - You can create users in IAM, assign them individual security credentials (i.e., access keys, passwords, and Multi-Factor Authentication devices) or request temporary security credentials to provide users access to AWS services and resources. You can manage permissions in order to control which operations a user can perform.

**Manage IAM roles and their permissions** - You can create roles in IAM, and manage permissions to control which operations can be performed by the entity, or AWS service, that assumes the role. You can also define which entity is allowed to assume the role.

**Manage federated users and their permissions** - You can enable identity federation to allow existing identities (e.g. users) in your enterprise to access the AWS Management Console, to call AWS APIs, and to access resources, without the need to create an IAM user for each identity.